# Can available network list box be launched in Win 10 kiosk using Shell Launcher v2?

Tags: windows, kiosk, kiosk-mode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher

**You can use a custom Windows desktop application that can then launch UWP apps, such as Settings and Touch Keyboard.**

I tried to launch available network list box in a kiosk implemented by Shell Launcher v2 using following code but failed.
Is this impossible or it’s just because I did it in a wrong way?

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
info.Arguments = "ms-availablenetworks:";
StartExeProcess(info);
```

Comment: Why Explorer.exe?

Comment: Cause this is the only command i Know to launch that network list box. 
explorer.exe  ms-availablenetworks:
I there anybody know its application file location? Even I launched that network list box, I can not find its process in the TaskManager, which is difficult for me to kill it.